# Convergence of partial p-series

Tags: power-series, divergent-series

I need find the exact value or at least to find a condition on $p$ and $k$ for which the following sum is finite:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=\left\lfloor n^{1/k}\right\rfloor }^\infty m^{-p}$$ for $p>1,k>1$.

---

We know (thanks alot to Meet Taraviya) that for $k=1$  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty m^{-p}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot n^{-p}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1-p}=\zeta(1-p)$$ where 
where $\zeta(p)$ is the Riemann zeta function thus it converges for $p>2$.

Are there any other solutions for different values of $k$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly when $k \geq 1$, since the terms are positive, you can rearrange the sums :

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=\lfloor n^{1/k}\rfloor}^\infty m^{-p} &= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^{(m+1)^k-1} m^{-p} \\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty ((m+1)^k-1)m^{-p}.
\end{align}
$$

Since

$$((m+1)^k-1)m^{-p} \sim m^{k-p}$$

when $m$ tends to $+\infty$, by comparison between series with non-negative terms, it converges iff $k-p<-1$, that is iff $p>k+1$.